# Foursquare api call my check-ins

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm having a big trouble to integrate foursquare API. 
All I want to do is get my check-ins from a specified timestamp.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [/users/checkins](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins) endpoint with the `beforeTimestamp`/`afterTimestamp` parameters to get check-ins for a time range.